# What is 'live class reloading' in tapestry.I want explanation in layman terms?

Tags: tapestry

Why one's actually use tapestry & mainly what is live class reloading in a simple term.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, live class reloading means you can make edits to your Java source code (the Tapestry-related parts, at least) and see the changes in the browser without having to stop and restart your web app.

https://tapestry.apache.org/class-reloading.html